# Properly defining a constant inside a Ruby Struct

Tags: ruby

I stumbled over a problem, which i present highly simplified here:

```
LDI = Struct.new(
  :dummy
) do
  SCORE_HIGHEST =  2
  def d
    dummy+1 
  end
end

# Using the constant defined in LDI
LDH = LDI::SCORE_HIGHEST
puts LDH
```

The idea here is that `Struct` is used to define a class which basically acts as a Container for several fields and puts for convenience more stuff in it. In the real application, there are of course more fields, more constants, and some methods to make the access easier.

Running this program with MRI Ruby 2.6.2 produces the **error** *uninitialized constant LDI::SCORE_HIGHEST (NameError)* for the line defining the constant LDH. Running it with JRuby 1.7 (which corresponds to MRI Ruby 1.9) and "warnings" enabled, correctly outputs the number `2`, but also a **warning**  *toplevel constant SCORE_HIGHEST referenced by LDI::SCORE_HIGHEST*.

It seems that what was only a warning in earlier Ruby versions, is now seen as error. Can someone explain exactly what's going on here?

I already found that obviously inside the `do....end` block of `Struct.new`, the constants are not bound to the class being defined, but on global scope. Indeed if I just reference it with SCORE_HIGHEST, without further qualification, it works. But why is it that defining methods does work - they become methods of the class LDI -, while defining constants does not?

And what's the best way to define such a constant? I found a solution, but I don't like so much:

I could take the constant definition into a separate `class` block (I added here for illustration one more method to make it clear why I don't like this way):

```
LDI = Struct.new(
  :dummy
) do
  def self.h
    LDI::SCORE_HIGHEST
  end
end
class LDI
  SCORE_HIGHEST =  2
end

puts  LDI.h
LDH = LDI::SCORE_HIGHEST
puts LDH
```

This works, but I have to prefix the name of the constant with the class name, LDI, even inside the definint block (as seen in the definition of method `h`).

Perhaps an alternative would be not to use constants, but just methods which return a constant value, i.e.

```
  def score_highest; 2; end
```

but this doesn't look very clever either.

Any better idea?

**UPDATE**: @Stefan suggested in his comment to prefix the constant by `self` inside the struct, but this doesn't seem to work either:

```
LDI = Struct.new(
  :dummy
) do
  self::SCORE_HIGHEST =  2
  def d
    dummy+1 
  end
end

# Using the constant defined in LDI
LDH = LDI::SCORE_HIGHEST
puts LDH
```

Yields error *uninitialized constant LDI::SCORE_HIGHTEST*

**UPDATE** The aforementioned error is not reproducible, The suggested code works indeed in a new irb session....

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate. TL;DL use `self::SCORE_HIGHEST` inside your struct.

Comment: Just noticed that you are the author of the other question, too! Seems like you encounter this problem every year on December 11 ;-)

Comment: @Stefan : Not exactly the same problem: In the first case, I had an outer class wrapped around it, and I was fine with associating the constant with the outer class. Now it is a stand-alone class, and I would like the constant to be part of the class generated by the `Struct`.

Comment: @Stefan : I have updated my question by incorporating your suggestion, which did not work for me - most likely because I misunderstood you with this. And you are right: December 11 seems to be "constant problem day" for me ....

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem. Pasting your (updated) code into IRB works just fine for me.

Comment: Another December mystery: I still have the IRB session open and can actually *see*  the error message, but when I open a new IRB, and paste the code, it works perfectly well. Hence, your suggestion does seem to work. If you make it an answer, I will accept it.